# Scraping data from the entire web

Tags: web-scraping

I need to develop a scraping tool that scrapes product's data (price, title etc) from the entire web. Now, I do have experience in scraping but that is for a single website. I am not sure how do I scrape the whole web. One possible solution is to query google and then scrape each website from the link appearing in google. Is this good approach?

I just need a general approach of how would you solve this problem because as I see it each site may have their own way of representing data. How do I incorporate all of these variations? Any guidelines/tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a built in multi website price comparison feature see: http://www.google.co.uk/shopping

You could try querying that resource using googles own custom search API or curl, though the API is probably a better choice as google is notoriously tricky to scrape and will probably lock up the IP if it thinks a curl script or similiar is being used.. The alternative is to  pull the data off somebody elses comparison site(s) if the idea of coding for multiple sites by hand fills you with dread.

Answer (score 1):

The term that defines what you're talking about is a **web crawler**. Have you looked at wikipedia's article?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler